# way ISNULL does not show colums if there is null?

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2, isnull

I have query

```
SELECT [Category] = ISNULL ( c.Category,'0'),
       COUNT (cl.ClientID) as [3 Mo Clients]
FROM Category c  LEFT JOIN clients cl ON cl.CategCode = c.CategCode 
WHERE agencyid =2
GROUP BY  c.Category, c.CategCode
```

its work  BUT  it must show all category from Category  table even if they are with null
but when i run my query  it looks like this 
[image]

category from Category table

```
Child
Infant
Newborn
Pregnant
Postpartum
Senior
```

Any Ideas way `ISNULL` doent work as it must be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you have filter the rows in the `WHERE` clause causing it to act like `INNER JOIN`. You need to put the condition in the `ON` clause because *I'm guessing that column `agencyid` is found on table `CategCode`*.

```
SELECT  [Category] = ISNULL ( c.Category,'0'),
        COUNT (cl.ClientID) as [3 Mo Clients]
FROM    Category c  
        LEFT JOIN clients cl 
           ON cl.CategCode = c.CategCode  AND 
              cl.agencyid = 2
GROUP   BY  c.Category, c.CategCode
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  [Category] = ISNULL ( c.Category,'0'),
        COUNT (cl.ClientID) as [3 Mo Clients],
        SUM(CASE WHEN statusid in (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) [Status_1_2]
FROM    Category c  
        LEFT JOIN clients cl 
           ON cl.CategCode = c.CategCode  AND 
              cl.agencyid = 2
GROUP   BY  c.Category, c.CategCode
```

Comment: Do you know how to add one more column which will count ClientID from clients table with `statusid in (1,2)` and show it same way? Because right now i cant add where clause.

Comment: have you tried using **IN**, `cl.agencyid IN (1,2)` instead of `cl.agencyid = 2`?

Comment: but i need one additional column. I tried `SELECT [Category] = ISNULL ( c.Category,'0'),
       COUNT (cl.ClientID) as [3 Mo Clients]
       ,(select COUNT(cl.ClientID) from clients cl where agencyID =2 and statusid in (1,2) group by cl.CategCode ) as '1'
FROM Category c  LEFT JOIN clients cl 
         ON cl.CategCode = c.CategCode  AND cl.agencyid =2
GROUP BY  c.Category, c.CategCode` but in third column it just show count for all clients with statis in (1,2)

Comment: hmm, so do you need to have two counts? one for every status? is that what you meam?

Comment: i need in first column it shows Category and it does in second  count all clients with agencyid =2 it does it, in therd i need count of clients with statusid in (1,2) and agencyid = 2

Comment: Awesome it works thank you so much, I was trying to use case but looks i did it wrong :)